# Drools Hot Deployment

Tags: drools, kie, drools-guvnor, kie-workbench

We are new to Drools Workbench 6.1 and we have some questions.

We want to do hot deployment on Drools. We have to see the change at the time in our application. We prepared our java programs with Maven. Do we need to restart the server every time after we have done the deployment process and created jar file? We don't want to do these operations. I look forward to your recommendations.

Best Regards.

Comment: What do you mean by "server"? A computer? A program?

Comment: We deploy our java codes to Websphere Unix Server with Jenkins Deployment tool. Actually we want to changes our rules without restart operation. We found some solutions in Drools 5 version but our system will be created on Drools 6. Is there any solutions about hot deployment? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can terminate the session, recreate the Knowledge Base and start another session. If your session has anything in Working Memory you'll need to analyse what and how to move over to the new session.